# Exception при попытке получить Connection из ConnectionPool

Tags: java-ee, servlet, tomcat, веб-сервер

Веб проект Java EE на сервлетах. В качестве контейнера используется Tomcat 9. Нужно написать `ConnectionPool`.

В корне проекта в папке `META-INF` лежит `context.xml`:

```
<Context>
    <Resource
            name="list"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxTotal="12"
            maxIdle="8"
            maxWaitMillis="10000"
            username="abc"
            password="abc"
            driverClassName="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/list" />
</Context>
```

В корне проекта в `WEB-INF` в `web.xml` :

```
<resource-ref>
        <description>MySQL DB Connection Pool</description>
        <res-ref-name>list</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Сам пул коннектов:

```
    public class ConnectionPool {
    private static DataSource dataSource;

    private ConnectionPool() {
    }

    static {
        try {
            InitialContext initContext= new InitialContext();
            dataSource  = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/list");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Приложение падает на строке создания `Connection` из `ConnectionPool`:

```
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

> update: привел имя к одному виду(что в context.xml, что в web.xml что
>   в ConnectionPool)

Теперь вместо NullPointer ловлю вот это:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Как дальше жить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш `ConnectionPool` написан совершенно неправильно. Вы зачем-то реализовали его как набор статических полей и методов. Инициализация поля `dataSource` У вас тоже статическая и в случае неудачи вы лишь распечатываете колстек исключения и продолжаете работать как ни в чём не бывало. При этом `dataSource` остаётся `null`, что и приводит к `NullPointerException` в `getConnection()`.

Comment: Такой подход описывает не один источник, в том числе и англоязычные. Не могли бы вы указать направление, как реализовать корректно пул? Корректную обработку исключений я выносил за скобки, хотелось бы сперва добиться работоспособности, а потом уже корректно отловить, вывести ошибку в консоль, упаковать в другое исключение и пробросить его выше

Comment: Идея была таковой: при загрузке класса проинициализируется dataSource, затем в конкретной имплементации DAO можно будет вытаскивать connection как ConnectionPool.getConnection()